# how to sort objects having nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I would like to know how to sort object containing nested array in javascript.
I have `obj` in which each property value (*color, product)* needs to be sorted by *label*

```
var obj = {
 color: [{id:1, label: "white"}, {id:2, label: "black"}, {id:3, label:"purple"}],
 product: [{id: 1, label: "women"},{id: 4, label: "men"}, {id: 3,label:"kids"}]
}

function sortobj(obj){
  var result = obj.forEach(grp => {
    return grp.sort((a, b) => a.label- b.label)
  })
  return result;
}

var result = sortobj(obj);
```

Expected Output

```
{
  color: [{id:2, label: "black"}, {id:3, label:"purple"}, {id:1, label: "white"}],
  product: [{id: 3,label:"kids"}, {id: 4, label: "men"}, {id: 1, label: "women"}]
}
```

Comment: None of your objects have a `.value` property...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

First call [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of *keys/values* from the object then  use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as follows:

```js
var obj = {
 color: [{id:1, label: "white"}, {id:2, label: "black"}, {id:3, label:"purple"}],
 product: [{id: 1, label: "women"},{id: 4, label: "men"}, {id: 3,label:"kids"}]
};

function sortObj(obj){
  return Object.entries(obj) // [['color', [{...}, {...}, ...]], ['product', [...]]]
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => 
    ({ ...acc, [key]: value.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label)) }), {});
    // or
    //(acc[key] = value.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label)), acc), {});
}

var result = sortObj(obj);

console.log(result);

//Expected Output
//  {
//  color: [{id:2, label: "black"}, {id:3, label:"purple"},{id:1, label: "white"}],
//  product: [{id: 3,label:"kids"},{id: 4, label: "men"},{id: 1, label: "women"}]
//  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to re-create the object in order to just sort the values of its properties?

Comment: it depends on the context, but we can also add new properties to the same object

Comment: We can do many things the question doesn't ask for. But this is very roundabout even if we chose to extend the object. There is no reason to either clone the object nor add any new properties. The original object also gets its array properties sorted in the meantime, so it seems wasteful and useless to create the clone.

Comment: so it's even useless to create the sort function and assign the result to another variable and we can just use the original object but that's what the OP asked for (if you look at the code provided)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to iterate over the keys (properties) of your original object, grab the value of every property and sort that by label.

```
function sortobj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((sortedObj, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    const sortedValue = value.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label));

    return {
      ...sortedObj,
      [key]: sortedValue
    };
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: Was there something not working in the solution I sketched?